# How to combine getElementByTagName and getElementByClass using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my selector so when it gets the class of transform with the tagname with p, it will do some event in my case it is mouse hovering but i am having trouble with it.

I know there are jquery solutions but i am doing it with pure javascript. here is the code below currently

```
var hoverEvent = document.getElementsByTagName("p").getElementsByClassName("transform");   

for (let i = 0; i < hoverEvent .length; i++) {
    hoverEvent [i].onmouseover=function() {
        this.style.color = "yellow";
     // changes paragraph with class of transform to yellow during hover
    }
}  // end for  

    for (let i = 0; i < hoverEvent .length; i++) {
    hoverEvent [i].onmouseout=function() {
        this.style.color = "black";
 // changes it back to black 
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use document.querySelectorAll("p.transform")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector in `querySelectorAll` to find all paragraphs with that classname:

```
var hoverEvent = document.querySelectorAll("p.transform");
```

Comment: @VSO Just to note, there's also `document.querySelector` that works the same way, but returns the first found element, or null while `querySelectorAll` returns a non-live NodeList.

Comment: Cool, I would add that to the answer. I already upvoted for cleanest answer. @Aeroy - this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var transformPs = document.querySelectorAll("p.transform");   

for (let i = 0; i < transformPs .length; i++) {
    // on mouse over
    transformPs[i].onmouseover = function () {
        this.style.color = "yellow";
        // changes paragraph with class of transform to yellow during hover
    };

    // on mouse out
    transformPs[i].onmouseout = function () {
        this.style.color = "black";
        // changes it back to black
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla JavaScript equivalent would be using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
function turnYellow (e) { e.target.style.color = 'yellow' }

function turnBlack (e) { e.target.style.color = '' }

document.querySelectorAll('p.transform').forEach(function (p) {
  p.addEventListener('mouseover', turnYellow)
  p.addEventListener('mouseout', turnBlack)
})
```

```css
body { background: #ccc; }
```

```html
<p class="transform">Example Paragraph</p>
```

However, I think the best approach would be to forego the JavaScript altogether and instead rely on the CSS pseudo-selector [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover):

```css
body { background: #ccc; }

p.transform:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p class="transform">Example Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **classList** to check class of element

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

if (p.classList.contains('transform')){ 
// do whatever you want to do 
}
```